# Is there a way to avoid setting parent of many to one relation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm creating REST service with spring with 2 entities: `Parent` and `Child`. Parent has many childs and child has one Parent. I also set `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`, so i calls save only for parent. I've got end point which takes json as input. Json contains `Parent` and some `Child`'s then i want to store it into database. The problem is that i need to explicitly wire Parent to Child, without it application stores null as foreign key.

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<Child> children;

    public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
        for(Child child : children){
            child.setParent(this);
        }
        this.children = children;
    }
}

@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    Parent parent;

}
```

Is there any (elegant) way to avoid the for loop in `setChildren`?

Comment: Well, since `Product.parent` is the owning side of the relation you need to set it - and since you want to cascade from the parent to the children you need the product to be present in `Parent.children` as well. If you want to keep it that way (and I don't see a reason why you'd want to change this) the loop would be required - IMO that loop isn't something you should worry about.

Comment: A demo can be found here: 
https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-mapping-example/#the-best-way-to-model-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-hibernate